# Python3: Matching elements between two lists based upon substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

This question is about matching strings in one list with matching strings
in another list. I was trying to figure out the best way to do this kind of matching. My example below is small, but I have to apply the same idea to a much larger list. So I have a set of filenames and paths in one list, 
and then I have a list of partial filenames in the other list, for
example:

```
    list1 = ['/../../abc_file1.txt',
             '/../../abc_extrafile1.txt',
             '/../../abc_file2.txt',
             '/../../abc_file3.txt',
             '/../../abc_extrafile3.txt']
```

And then I have a different list

```
    ['file1', 'extrafile1', 'file2', 'file3', 'extrafile3']
```

So what I would like to do is get a matching that generates a dictionary like:

```
    {'file1': '/../../abc_file1.txt',
     'extrafile1': '/../../abc_extrafile1.txt',
     'file2': '/../../abc_file2.txt',
     'file3': '/../../abc_file3.txt',
     'extrafile3': '/../../abc_extrafile3.txt'}
```

So there are some overlaps between the filenames, and I need to 
be careful of that.

There are a number of ways to do something like this, but I was not sure which was the most efficient for matching lists on the order of 1000 or 10,000 entries. Seems like this might be done through a dictionary comprehension or a lambda, but seems a bit complicated. I could write a raw loop, but that does not seem particularly efficient.

Any suggestions on how to manage this type of matching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a `dict comprehension` as you've suggested and check against a `split` of the first list element (to take into account the overlaps) and removing the extensions:

```
list1 = ['/../../abc_file1.txt',
             '/../../abc_extrafile1.txt',
             '/../../abc_file2.txt',
             '/../../abc_file3.txt',
             '/../../abc_extrafile3.txt']

list2 = ['file1', 'extrafile1', 'file2', 'file3', 'extrafile3']

my_dict = {k: v for v in list1 for k in list2 if k == v.split('_')[1][:-4]}
```

**output**:

```
{'file1': '/../../abc_file1.txt', 'extrafile1': '/../../abc_extrafile1.txt', 'file2': '/../../abc_file2.txt', 'file3': '/../../abc_file3.txt', 'extrafile3': '/../../abc_extrafile3.txt'}
```

Comment: Okay, this is very helpful. Cool that using a dictionary comprehension can work here. Do you think that sorting the `list1`  or `list2` has any benefit? In other words, does the conditional statement find the first match or the last match, etc?

Comment: I don't see much benefit in sorting the lists beforehand and the dict comp will loop through every element even after finding a match, if it finds another match it will replace the value for the existing key inside the dict.

Comment: Okay got it. So it will basically always find the last match. Makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are two loops hidden in the comprehension. Please check my answer below for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensions are just a simpler way to write collection-building-loops. Easier to the eye, no necessarily efficient.

In @matt-b answer, the `dict comprehension` hides a double `for` loop, making the comprehension pretty slow with large lists (n-squared complexity).

Your specific problem can be solved with a simple loop, keeping the complexity linear.

With this input:

```
size = 1000
list1 = [ '/../../abc_file' + str(i) + '.txt' for i in range(size) ]
list2 = [ 'file' + str(i) for i in range(size) ]
```

The `dict comprehension` takes around 500ms on my machine:

```
my_dict = {k: v for v in list1 for k in list2 if k == v.split('_')[1][:-4]}

# 1 loop, best of 3: 516 ms per loop
```

The following version is faster, at around 1ms:

```
res = { k: None for k in list2 }
for v in list1:
    name = v.split('_')[-1][:-4]
    if name in res:
        res[name] = v

# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.15 ms per loop
```

With this structure, it is easy to keep multiple matches if needed:

```
res = { k: [] for k in list2 }
for v in list1:
    name = v.split('_')[-1][:-4]
    if name in res:
        res[name].append(v)

# 100 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
```

You could also keep the first match by checking the current `res[name]` values against `None`.